# Performance of float vs double with GCC, Intel & MS C

Tags: floating-point, double, benchmarking, sse, avx

I have seen the previous ancient x87 era thread on this and thought it was time to revisit it in the modern era of SSE2 & AVX. The results of my fairly simple C benchmark test were mostly what I expected but with a few surprises. I'd be interested to know the correct timings for this benchmark on Unix based GCC not hobbled by using MinGW FP library.

I chose a relatively dense complex "representative" piece of numerical code (sorry about the length it is as short as I could make it). It is a cubic starter for solving Kepler's equation which happens to use most of the common functions (it could be modified to use exp & log with a DIY cube root but I have pared it down to the bare minimum that still works in float and double).

These are the timings in machine cycles for double precision 64 bit reals and 32 bit floats on each compiler. The compilers are Intel 2023, MSC 2022 and GCC 13.1.0(MinGW port) all x64 except for doing the x87 tests. My GCC results are dodgy since the Mingw FP library uses 80bit x87 mode for sin,cos,exp,log & atan2. I've corrected them by a best guess estimate of the overheads to those x87 instructions. I also might not be using the optimum compiler settings since I am new to GCC. They were done on an i5-12600 CPU OS Win 11 pro 64.

```
gcc -O3 -Ofast -march=native -mavx -mfpmath=sse benchbasic.cpp
```

[image: Double precision timings]

[image: Float timings]

The first surprise to me was how similar they are - only on the MS compiler is there an appreciable performance increase going from double to float. The second observation is that the Intel results are suspiciously fast. This is because it has found a way to entirely vectorise the problem and do it as 2 or 4 consecutive values of M at a time. I know that GCC can do this too from other tests but it doesn't if there are if statements involved. MSC is treating the vector FP registers as scalars so that SSE2 is probably the best buy there. Legacy x87 float 32bit code seems to get slower compiled on Intel & MS - no idea why. Counter intuitive!

Intel also cheats by using the much faster SSE2 library code for trig when in x87 mode. It also swaps pow(x,1.0/3) for cbrt(x) and other cute transforms (-Ofast). Both the other compilers used the x87 opcodes directly. At -O3 all the compilers have inlined most of the code because it is single use but the results are almost the same if I take steps to prevent this happening. x87 80 bit floats (long double on GCC & Intel with certain options set) is best avoided but can be useful sometimes for accumulating sums of doubles.

There is one other curiosity that I discovered whilst tidying this up so that the timings lined up nicely on an 80 column screen. Deleting a few spaces from a string in a printf radically changed the timings when the MS compiled code is run in the Microsoft VC debugger up from 250 to ~1000. I would really like to know why this is! It seemed reproducible for a while (but it isn't) - and it always runs at full speed if run from the command line.

There is a smaller systematic variation in execution times with static data length that I suspect is due to MSC putting compiler generated long AVX structures onto the stack and sometimes crossing a cache line boundary.

Here is the code - it should compile unmodified on most systems. It measures throughput rather than latency as presently configured (relevant metric for my problem).

```
// BenchBasic.cpp : This is a simple benchmark. float vs double
// define symbol ALLDOUBLE to switch to doubles

#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C
#include <math.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h> 

//#define ALLDOUBLE

#ifdef ALLDOUBLE
#define float double
#define sinf(x) sin(x)
#define sqrtf(x) sqrt(x)
#define cbrtf(x) cbrt(x)
#define atan2f(x,y) atan2(x,y)
#define fabsf(x) fabs(x)
#endif 


double QuickTime(double (*func)(double, double), const char* name)
{ 
  double dM, E, M;
  uint64_t start, end;
  unsigned int aux;
  time_t  start_t, end_t;
  int j, k, cycles;
  const int MDIV = 10000000;
  end = end_t = 0; // to stop compiler warnings
  E = M = 1e-10;   // some routines don't like 0 as an input
  dM = (M_PI - M) / (MDIV - 1);
  printf("\n%10s %i", name, 0); 
//  printf("\n%10s", name); // uncomment this line for 4x faster in MSVC debug!
  for (j = 0; j < 39; j++)
  {
    E = 0;
    end_t = clock();
    while (end_t == (start_t = clock()))
        ; // sync start tick
    start = __rdtscp(&aux);
    for (k = 0; k < MDIV; k++)
    {
        E += (*func)(M, 0.7);
        M += dM;
    }
    end = __rdtscp(&aux);
    if (E == 42) printf("\nI hate global optimisers\n"); 
    // side effect added to defeat global optimisers nulling out code
    end = end - start;  // CPU cycles approx 
    end_t = clock() - start_t;
    cycles = (int)((end + MDIV / 2) / MDIV);
    printf(" %5i %5.3f", cycles, (double)end_t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  }
  return E;
}

double BasicF32(double ed, double Md)
{
// this 32 bit implementation uses cubic solver inline NB a,b divided by 3 at source
// Also has problems with some awkward values like e = 0.85, M = 0.70
// Cubic solver can overflow since there is not enough headroom on the 
// exponent max(tan(E)) ~ 10^7 and (10^7)^6 = 10^42 > 10^38
// Cubic solver needs additional work to protect against overflows

 float  a, b, c, d, e2, e, E, f3, M, q, r, r2, s, s2, t;
 if (Md == 0) return Md;
 M = (float)Md;
 e = (float)ed;
 e2 = e * e;
 s = sinf(M / 2);
 s2 = s * s;
 s2 += s2;
 s = sinf(M);
 f3 = 60 * (1 - e) + e2 * (3 + 7 * e) - (60 + 3 * e2) * s2;
 if (f3 == 0)   f3 = 1e-6f;  // defend against f3 == 0 when M~=pi/2-e
 a = -(20 + e2) * s / f3;    // a/3
 b = 20 * (1 - e - s2) / f3; // b/3
 c = -30 * s / f3;           // c/2
// start of cubic solver
 q = b - a * a;
 r = 1.5f * a * b - c - a * a * a;
 r2 = r * r;
 d = q * q * q + r2;
 if (d < 0) d = 0; // these problems should only have one real root.
 if (r2 < d * 0.0001f)
 { // avoid catastrophic canellation of roots
    s = 2 * r / (3 * cbrtf(d));
    t = r * r / (27 * d);
    t = s * (1 + t*(5 + 66 * t)) - a; // next highest order
 }
 else
 {
    d = sqrtf(d);
    if (r > 0)
        s = cbrtf(r + d);
    else
        s = -cbrtf(d - r);
    if (s != 0) t = s - q / s - a;
    else t = -a;  // special case arises when e=1 and M=0 or pi
 }
 if (t * M < 0) a = -1;  else a = 1;
 E = atan2f(a * t, a);
 if (fabsf(E) < fabsf(M)) E = M; // defensive fix for M~=pi rounding errors
 return E;
}

int main()
{
  QuickTime(BasicF32, "Basic");
}
```

It is entirely possible I have slipped up somewhere so it would be interesting to know how it performs on a few other high end CPUs. There is a known problem in the float 32 bit code affecting less than 0.1% of the range of M where tan exceeds 3e6. I don't think it is altering the timings unduly (but I could be wrong).

What is other peoples experience of the advantages and disadvantages of floats vs doubles on modern SSE2/AVX hardware? I had expected floats to be faster doing lower precision trig etc. I am therefore more than a bit surprised by these results.

Comment: For basic operations (add/sub/mul/fma) other than div/sqrt, scalar should be the same speed in the ALUs.  Math library functions like exp/log and trig functions typically need larger polynomials to get a result with close to 52 mantissa bits of precision instead of 23, so they're normally slower.  `double` costs twice the memory bandwidth / cache footprint, and for SIMD vectorization only half as many elements fit in a vector, so those effects are significant when doing stuff like matmul.

Comment: On i7-6700k Skylake at 3.9GHz, your benchmark runs in 23.9 seconds, and prints out `Basic 0   260 0.647   252 0.629   249 0.621   245 0.611   245 0.611   248 0.618   245 0.611   245 0.611` ... mostly the same ... `245 0.612   245 0.611   245 0.612`, whatever that means.  (I haven't looked at what it does yet.)  Compiled with x86-64 GCC on Arch GNU/Linux, with glibc 2.38-7, GCC13.2.1), with `gcc -O3 -ffast-math -Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries fpbench.c -lm` (SSE2).

Comment: With AVX2+FMA (adding `-march=native`=skylake), 24.3s total, `Basic 0   265 0.662   258 0.642   256 0.634   249 0.622   249 0.621   249 0.622   250 0.622` ... mostly the same 249-251 ... `248 0.619   249 0.622   249 0.621   249 0.620`.  Counts from `perf stat` show AVX saved instructions and front-end uops (`uops_issued.any` 143G down from 152G), but back-end uops were nearly the same (`uops_executed.thread` 152G AVX up from 149.7G SSE2).  Extra `movaps` register copies are eliminated (costing front-end but not back-end), and `vaddsd xmm0, xmm0, [rdi + rsi*8]` un-laminates unlike the SSE ver.

Comment: The asm doesn't actually have any insns that would un-laminate like `vaddss xmm0, xmm0, [rdi + rsi*4]`, so probably it's just mov-elimination that's making the back-end counts about the same.  IDK why it comes out slightly slower with AVX2+FMA, I didn't look into what the bottlenecks are yet.  At an average of 1.59 IPC, the front-end probably isn't usually a bottleneck.  It does some div and sqrt but doesn't bottleneck on it: `arith.divider_active` only counts 9.5G cycles out of 94.3 giga-cycles for the whole thing.  (AVX+FMA version, with `-fno-plt` as well to reduce lib call overhead; 24.2s)

Comment: GCC can auto-vectorize math functions when libmvec is available.  https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec has an example that uses `#pragma omp simd`, and a second example that works with GCC6 or later just using `-ffast-math` and `-ftree-loop-vectorize` (which is on at `-O3` or `-Ofast`). That auto-vectorizes for me, but your code doesn't, maybe due to the branching :/  `-fopt-info-vec-missed` says one of the loops can't be vectorized because the iteration count can't be computed (ahead of the first iteration).

Comment: clang 16.0.6 with `-O3 -ffast--fno-plt`: SSE2 baseline build: 24.1s `Basic 0   264 0.658   257 0.641   253 0.630   247 0.617` ... `250 0.624   247 0.616   247 0.616` vs. `-march=native` (skylake AVX2+FMA) 21.9s total, `Basic 0   245 0.610   236 0.590   232 0.578` ... `225 0.561   225 0.561`

Comment: @Peter Cordes sorry about that they are respectively time in cycles and clock time in seconds (and enough repeats to be clear of any start up effects). The slow fp trig was a big surprise to me taking almost the same in single as double precision although it was calling _trigf and the code looked shorter to me. MSC is slower in part because it is careless about putting things on the stack rather more than the others. Thanks for the pointer to libmvec as I said before I am at novice level on GCC so expect to make mistakes. Thanks also for running the BM. My guess of ~240 was not far off.

Comment: Cycles?  Oh, *reference* cycles from the TSC (*[How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907627)* has TSC details).  On my CPU, the reference clock runs at 4008 MHz.  With the energy-performance-preference setting I use, cores actually run at 3.9 GHz max, so 250 TSC ticks is about `250 * 3900/4008 = 243.26` core clock cycles.  You'd need `rdpmc` and a system call to get the kernel to program the HW performance counters if you wanted to measure core clock cycles from user-space directly.